# Apache RedirectMatch with Regex

Tags: regex, apache

I'm trying to redirect every URL that have no `#` to the same, but with `#` after `/path/`.

Example:

This URL: `https://www.example.com/path/test/test`

Need redirect to this url: `https://www.example.com/path/#/test/test`

So I wrote this Redirect Match:

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^/path/(?!#)(.*)$ /path/#/$2
```

But it's not working.

Browser shows me this message: `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`

Comment: Actually a lookahead (either positive or negative) is a non-capturing group. Then in your expression `$2` will always remain empty, as the text following `path/` will be captured in group 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use this rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?(path)/(.+)$ /$1/#/$2 [L,NE,NC,R=301]
```

It will redirect `/path/test/test` to `/path/#test/test`.

There is no need to check for presence of `#` in `RewriteRule` because client browsers don't send any part after `#` to web server anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
RedirectMatch ^/path/([^#]+)$ /path/#/$1
```

The captured group `([^#]+)` represents any string, minimum 1 character, that doesn't contain `#`.

Comment: when i try to access `/path/something`, i was redirected to `/path/#` only, without `something` parameter :/

Comment: I don't see any problem with the regex when testing it, so it may be that the /something segment is being stripped out after the match and replace for some reason.